# "XHZ64408" does not have the privilege to perform operation "IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA"

Tags: db2, cloud, schema, websphere

I am unable to create a table on IBM Db2 on cloud.. what is the reason for this error ?

Status:
Failed

Error message
"XHZ64408" does not have the privilege to perform operation "IMPLICIT CREATE SCHEMA".. SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502, DRIVER=4.25.1301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your user doesn’t have the `IMPLICIT_SCHEMA` database authority to create schemas implicitly in the database.
[Database authorities](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005524.html).

> **IMPLICIT_SCHEMA**
>
> Allows any user to create a schema implicitly by creating an object
>   using a CREATE statement with a schema name that does not already
>   exist. SYSIBM becomes the owner of the implicitly created schema and
>   PUBLIC is given the privilege to create objects in this schema.

You are probably allowed to create objects in the `XHZ64408` schema only.
You may check it using the [SYSCAT.SCHEMAAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001058.html) view.